# How to retrieve column value from table1 and keep it in table2's column?

Tags: mysql, ruby, csv, activerecord, rubygems

Table_1:

```
ID |   Name    | Address
1  |  prakash  | 2-107, NY
2  |  rakesh   | 2-109/a, NY
```

Table_2:

```
emp_ID| Name    | Designation
   ?  | Prakash | Software Developer
   ?  | Rakesh  | Software Tester
```

By using the Name column in the table-2, I need to get the id from the table-1 and place it in the table-2.

```
require 'csv'
load 'dbconnection.rb'
require 'activerecord'


class Employee<ActiveRecord::Base

end

class Designation<ActiveRecord::Base
end

#Employee  Table Data Insertion
CSV.foreach("C:/Users/modi/Desktop/employee.csv") do |row|
    Employee.create!(
        # ID will be auto increement 
        :name => row[0],
        :address => row[1],
        )
    end


#Designation Table Data Insertion

CSV.foreach('C:/Users/modi/Desktop/designation.csv') do |row|

    Designation.create!(
        :Emp_id #Here we need to get the id value from the Employee Table
        :name => row[0],
        :designation=>row[1]
        )           
    end
```

Comment: does your csv file have headers?

Comment: No i am not using @shivam

Comment: just to be clear, are these both `CSV.foreach` part of same file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Employee` does not contain enormous amount of data, you can do this:

```
employees = Employee.all
CSV.foreach('C:/Users/modi/Desktop/designation.csv') do |row|
  Designation.create!(
    :Emp_id => employees.detect { |emp| emp.name == row[0] }.id # handle nil case
    :name => row[0],
    :designation=>row[1]
  )           
end
```

Comment: suggest me some links and books for changing my designation to __Programmer__ from __Beginner__

Comment: I am a learner myself. Best I can advice is keep writing codes and google/SO when stuck. :)